# Citation List: Putting edition, volume, pages together in parentheses

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I'm trying to customize a .bst file, and I'm in desperate need of some assistance.

I have a citation that looks like this:
[image: citation]

After the title of the book, I'm trying to put parentheses around the edition, volume, number, and pages. I am able to do each individually [e.g., (Vol. 14), (pp. 207-262)] but not around everything in one set of parentheses [i.e., (Vol. 14, pp. 207-262)].

This reference is an "incollection".

Also, is there anyway to suppress the comma the occurs before?

So that it looks like this:
... *Advances in research and theory* (Vol. 14, pp. 207-262). New York: Academic Press.

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check

      format.edition output
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output

      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

And here's my .bst file in its entirety: https://pastebin.com/ZQNx0P9U (Was too long to post here.)

And here's the .bib entry:

```
@incollection{RaaiShif80,
        Address = {New York},
        Author = {Raaijmakers, J. G. W. and Shiffrin, R. M.},
        Booktitle = {The psychology of learning and motivation: Advances in research and theory},
        Date-Added = {2014-09-10 12:47:36 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2014-09-10 12:47:54 +0000},
        Editor = {G. H. Bower},
        Pages = {207-262},
        Publisher = {Academic Press},
        Title = {{SAM: A} theory of probabilistic search of associative memory},
        Volume = {14},
        Year = {1980}}
```

And a sample .tex file:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

```
\begin{document}

\section*{Sample Citation}

This is a sample citation: \cite{RaaiShif80}.

\bibliographystyle{mybst.bst}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You've tagged this post as `biblatex`, but you don't seem to use it. Could you post a full, yet minimal, compilable code?

Comment: It would be easier to do with `biblatex` – at least for me.

Comment: You need to modify the functions `format.bvolume` and `format.chapter.pages`, to place parentheses around their respective contents. Since you haven't revealed how these functions are defined, it's not possible to give specific advice for now on how you might go about achieving your formatting objective.

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks for looking into this. I did post my .bst file in its entirety at: https://pastebin.com/ZQNx0P9U It was too long for the character limit of the post. Wouldn't altering these functions put parentheses around the items individually and not collectively?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem so first I create this function to create parentheses

```
FUNCTION {parens}    
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ "(" swap$ * ")" * }
if$
}
```

but this will work just for volume or just for pages. I think you should create a new format with volume and pages. Something like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
pages empty$
    'skip$
    { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ", " * pages n.dashify * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Then, you need to remove the comma. You need to create another function

```
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

and include command `parens` and `add.blank` before your function for volume and pages, in your code

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.sentence
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check

      format.edition output
      add.blank
      format.vol.pages parens "volume and pages" output.check
      format.number.series output

      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I've edited it @flav